# jQuery plugin to create awesome scroll down experience

Tags: jquery

I have no idea if this technique has a name already but I have seen it in a number of sites recently. The last one (and one of the most impressive) is

```
http://www.discovershadow.com/
```

Anyone knows if this technique has a name? Even better any jQuery plugins that can help you reach such results? The closest plugin that could assist in creating something like that withought writing too much code is the jQuery scroll path

```
http://joelb.me/scrollpath/
```

but still I was wondering if there is some better, more suitable option.

Comment: There is no plugin. It just involves listening to the `$(window).scroll` event, and then performing certain actions, such as restyling the elements and etc. Check the inspector.

Comment: The scroll path plugin is a nice way as I mention but was trying to figure out if there's something even better suited ;)
Plain js is always an option but time consuming!

Comment: Effects like that are quite customized anyway — so instead of spending time trying to make a plugin work the way you want, it's probably just as efficient as writing your own script.

Answer (score 1):

this plugin can help you http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage
but you have to use your own css tricks like playing with `z-index` of different images on the scrolling area

Answer (score 0):

You can use [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

It is a full blown animation library, just look at the example sites and you will see what can it be created with it. Also, here is the link to the particular effect that you are after:

[image zoom](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-zoom-into-an-image-on-scroll/)